# return null when calculate time in maria db

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE T_WorkContents (
user_id varchar(5),
working_date DATE NOT NULL,
working_start_time TIME NOT NULL,
working_end_time TIME NOT NULL,
break_time TIME DEFAULT '0',
holiday_mark tinyint DEFAULT '0',
overtime_hours TIME DEFAULT '0',
overtime_reason TEXT,
work_detail TEXT,
remarks TEXT,
regist_user varchar(5),
regist_date DATETIME,
update_user varchar(5),
update_date DATETIME,
delete_flag tinyint DEFAULT '0', 
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, working_date),
FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES T_UserInfo(user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE T_UserInfo (
user_id varchar(5) NOT NULL,
user_name varchar(30),
password varchar(20) NOT NULL,
authority tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
regist_user varchar(5),
regist_date datetime,
update_user varchar(5),
update_date datetime,
delete_flag tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY(user_id),
FOREIGN KEY(authority) REFERENCES T_Authority(authority)
);
```

and the sql script like this

```
SELECT t.user_id, u.user_name, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,     TIME(t.working_start_time), TIME(t.working_end_time))) AS total_time, SUM(TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, TIME(CONVERT('00:00:00',TIME)), TIME(t.overtime_hours)))) AS overtime , SUM(TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, TIME(CONVERT('00:00:00',TIME)), Time(t.break_time))) )AS break_time , COUNT(*) AS count_day ,MONTH(t.working_date) as working_month,YEAR(t.working_date) AS working_year FROM T_WorkContents AS t INNER JOIN T_UserInfo AS u ON u.user_id = t.user_id WHERE t.delete_flag = 0 AND u.delete_flag = 0  AND MONTH(t.working_date) = 4 AND YEAR(t.working_date) = 2015 GROUP BY t.user_id, working_month ,working_year;
```

after I execute the script I get the following result

[image]

What could possibly goes wrong in here?

Comment: TIMESTAMPDIFF() expects a datetime, not a time value, and TIME() returns a string, not a time. Try using TIMEDIFF() function, and use it on the fields themselves, not on the TIME() function result

Comment: great. i just posted it as an answer if you can be bothered accepting it :)

Answer (score 0):

TIMESTAMPDIFF() expects a datetime, not a time value, and TIME() returns a string, not a time. Try using TIMEDIFF() function, and use it on the fields themselves, not on the TIME() function result